# Compare two tables in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

If I have two tables `Grades` and `StudentsMark` like this:

Table **Grades**

```
StudentId    Mark    examId 
---------------------------
1              10     1
2              9      2
3              15     1
4              26     3
```

Table **StudentMark**:

```
StudentId    Mark     examid
-----------------------------
1              10      1
2              5       2
3              15      1
4              8       3
```

And I want to compare the data between this two table , and if there different in mark I want to replace the `grade(mark)` with `StudentMark(Mark)` using the bulk

How to do that ?

Comment: Could you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

Use **`JOIN`** with **`UPDATE`** and update only the one is different by checking it in **`WHERE`** clause.

**Query**

```
update t1
set t1.[Mark] = t2.[Mark]
from [grade] t1
join [StudentMark] t2
on t1.[StudentId] = t2.[StudentId]
where t1.[Mark] <> t2.[Mark];
```

Comment: Iam insert the values to studentsMark table from a file  using bulk insert 
and now I want to update the values using the bulk update

Comment: @Moh You dont need to use bulk update. You just need to update after your insert statement.

Comment: @plaidDK  I know that but my trainer asked me to use it

Comment: @Moh You could also this is some kinda of bulk load since its being joined on each studentid.